# Is the Matrix protocol Fediverse?

Tags: network-protocols

The title says it all. Reading about the Fediverse, the Matrix protocol seems to fit its characteristics, however I found no reference of that anywhere.

Comment: There can be no definitive answer to this question as "Fediverse" has no standards-based definition, so all answers to the question will be opinion based.

Answer (score 2):

Yes Matrix it definitely is a Fediverse protocol. See for example this old site: https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/business/self-hosted-matrix-with-riot-team-chat-under-your-control

It is weird, Wikipedia page for Matrix  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_(protocol)
says only
" ... protocol for federated real-time communication."
and
"See also Fediverse"
..which leaves it ambiguous ...

and it doesn't seem to have a reference to Matrix on pages I would have expected to see it:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_software_and_protocols_for_distributed_social_networking

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse

... nor a reference to "Fediverse" on this page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federation_(information_technology)

Do you think Wikipedia is slanted to make certain things obscure? Or just not always helpful?

If you're interested, Episode 180 of Destination Linux podcast covered Matrix recently - they were all of the opinion that it will become *the* main standard for non-commercial messaging etc. https://destinationlinux.org/

I use Element, (formerly known as Riot.im until recently) which is a message client using the Matrix protocol.

Regards

Comment: Some articles in wikipedia may need improvement, as some question&answers in stackexchange. Hopefully, both have an edit button.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see, the Matrix protocol and the protocol used for the Fediverse ([ActivityPub](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ActivityPub)) are incompatible.

The [wikipedia page on Fediverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fediverse) (the ActivityPub universe) has an image showing the Matrix protocol outside of its universe.

This article indicates they are not compatible : https://fedi-verse.info/matrix-synapse

There's a good comparison of the features here : http://blog.misterblue.com/2020/2020-08-11-ActivityPub-and-Matrix-for-Vircadia

So, the logic and decentralised nature are similar, but they are not compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix is a federated protocol. It's currently used mainly for group chat rooms, although an experimental [microblogging app for matrix called Cerulean](https://matrix.org/blog/2020/12/18/introducing-cerulean/) was released at the end of 2020, and there's a [web commenting system called Cactus Comments that uses matrix](https://cactus.chat/).

The fediverse began as the informal name for a network of social media servers that federated using a protocol called OStatus, developed for the StatusNet software originally used by Identi.ca. Since then, all of those apps have added support for a newer W3C web standard for federated social media, called ActivityPub, as have a number of apps that were federating using Diaspora's bespoke version of OStatus. [Dozens a new federated social media apps have since been developed using AP](https://fediverse.party/en/miscellaneous/).

Although the definitional boundaries of the fediverse are fuzzy, it's usually thought to include any app that supports AP, or that federates with an AP app using another protocol. For example, Friendica, SocialHome, and Hubzilla all implement now AP, but still support the Diaspora protocol. So even though [Diaspora doesn't implement AP itself](https://discourse.diasporafoundation.org/t/lets-talk-about-activitypub/741), it is generally considered part of the fediverse.

Matrix apps do not implement AP, nor do they federate with any apps that do AFAIK. So it's generally not considered part of the fediverse. But what if Cerulean or Cactus Comments implemented support for AP, or an existing AP implemented enough of the matrix spec to federate with them? Or what if an AP app added a realtime chat feature using matrix? Then matrix might start to be included as a fediverse protocol.